# isolated scope "=" affects parent scope

Tags: angularjs

in the directive, define scope:{isoNetwork:'=network'}, if the parent scope has no 'network' property, it will auto create it? 
following pic is parent scope:
[image]

here is the code example(same in jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yougen/mvYrJ/7/):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.leaveVoicemail = function(number, message, network){
       console.log("controller scope: ", $scope);
       window.alert("Number: " + number + " said: " + message + ", by network: " + network);
   };
});

app.directive('phone', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            isolatedAttributeNumber:'@number',
            isoNetwork:'=network',
            makeCall:'&'
        },
        link:function(scope){
            scope.networks = ["Verizon", "AT&T", "Sprint"];
            scope.isoNetwork = scope.networks[1];
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <phone number="555-1234" network="network" make-call="leaveVoicemail(number, message, network)">
            <div>
                Number:{{isolatedAttributeNumber}}  Network:<select ng-model="isoNetwork" ng-options="net for net in networks"></select>
            </div>
            Your message:<input type="text" ng-model="voiceMessage"><br>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="makeCall({number: isolatedAttributeNumber, message: voiceMessage, network: isoNetwork})">Call Home!</button>
        </phone>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not working.

Comment: sorry, I have fixed the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  That is how `=` bindings in the isolate scope work.  The directive gets its own scope, but you still need a way of communicating with the outside scope (not "parent" scope since the directive's scope is isolated).

The `=` binding provides a two-way binding to the outside.  So, when you bound your model in the directive `<phone nework="network" ...`, you are telling Angular to set the `network` value in your controller's scope.  This happens inside your `link` function when you set `isoNetwork`.

If you are looking for a one-way binding, consider the `@` binding, which is a one-way string binding, which is different from the `=` binding which is a two-way reference.